# How do I capture a key press (or keydown) event on a div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting, keypress

How do you trap the keypress or key down event on a DIV element (using jQuery)?

What is required to give the DIV element focus?

Comment: What does "focus" mean for a div?

Comment: jboyd other than tabbing to it when it has a tabindex, you can use javascript to find it and call the focus method on it.

Comment: @Lalchand ... can you accept my answer somewhen? :)

Answer (score 371):

(1) Set the `tabindex` attribute:

```
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="0" />
```

(2) Bind to keydown:

```
 $('#mydiv').on('keydown', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.keyCode);
    switch(event.keyCode){
       //....your actions for the keys .....
    }
 });
```

To set the focus on start:

```
$(function() {
   $('#mydiv').focus();
});
```

To remove - if you don't like it - the `div` focus border, set `outline: none` in the CSS.

See the table of [keycodes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) for more `keyCode` possibilities.

All of the code assuming you use jQuery.

#

Comment: +1 tabindex is the key point here to make the div 'selectable'. JQuery not necessary, the same thing works with Angular as well as (I suppose) with plain javascript events.

Comment: What's the browser support for this?

Comment: tabindex is a key part, but do not set it to any value other than "0". Making it anything above 0 is going to mess up screen readers for visually impaired users (it will skip everything on the page and go straight to any tabindex above 0). tabindex="0" makes it "tabbable." you can have infinite elements with tabindex="0"

Comment: Works with <pre> as well!

Comment: Excellent! I was missing the tabindex attribute, maybe because DIV's can't receive focus unless they have a tabindex. Thanks man! Saved my life! EDIT: works with React as well

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated.
It's should use .on('keydown',.. instead off .bind('keydownm..
http://api.jquery.com/bind

Comment: It's worth noting that while `keydown` works just fine, `keypress` does not. (At least in my situation with an `<li>` on Chrome.)

Comment: One helle of a good answer!

Comment: Note the javascript attribute is `tabIndex` not `tabindex` (capital i).

Answer (score 17):

Here example on plain JS:

```js
document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  console.log(e.key)
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div 
  id="myDiv"
  tabindex="0"
>
  Press me and start typing
</div>
```

Comment: I would use a `tabindex="-1"` since "Keyboard events are only generated by <inputs>, <textarea> and anything with the contentEditable attribute or with tabindex="-1"." [MDN Element: keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)

Answer (score 9):

**tabindex** HTML attribute indicates if its element can be focused, and if/where it participates in sequential keyboard navigation (usually with the `Tab` key). Read [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) for full reference.

#### Using Jquery

```js
$( "#division" ).keydown(function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    console.log("keydown: " + evt.keyCode);
});
```

```css
#division {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="division" tabindex="0"></div>
```

#### Using JavaScript

```js
var el = document.getElementById("division");

el.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    console.log("keydown: " + evt.keyCode);
};
```

```css
#division {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="division" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: i actually found this looking for an issue with the focusout event firing when the controls on the div lost focus say to click on the divs scrollbar , simply adding the tabstop to the div was the fix, so thank you so much