# how to capture any key events in the page from div tag?

Tags: javascript

Can any one tell me how to capture key events in div tag??

I wrote this code but it is not working?

```
<div id="SDiv" style="background-color: White; " onkeypress="kypress()">
     <asp:Label ID="LblSaveAndMoveNext" runat="server" Visible="False" Text="Save"></asp:Label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function kypress() { EnableButtons(true);}
</script>
```

Comment: div tag is not such tag which you can set focus to.

Comment: you must set focus to the div first.check this link for more info 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capturing-key-press-event-in-div.

Comment: Then how to achieve .In my page i don't have form tag.My requirement is when I press any key in the page i should call kypress() function.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a focus in order to trigger the keypress event.

Or you could apply the keypress on the document object.

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).keypress(function(){
     /*do something*/
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Only elements that can receive focus, such as inputs and other form-related elements, will fire key events. To force a `<div>` element to be able to receive focus, you can either make it contenteditable, which is probably not what you want, or add a `tabindex` attribute. Using a value of 0 will place the element at the default position in the tab order.

```
<div id="SDiv" tabindex="0" style="background-color: White;"
     onkeypress="kypress()">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome it by using a contenteditable div, like this. Make sure you return false to prevent the changes in html.

```
    <div  id="SDiv" contenteditable="true" 
    style="background-color: White; " tab-index="1" onkeydown="return keydown();">
       <asp:Label ID="LblSaveAndMoveNext" runat="server" Visible="False" Text="Save"></asp:Label>           
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function keydown(){
            var keyCode = event.which;
            if(keyCode==13)
                document.write('You pressed Enter');
            //do your logic here
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the thread "[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed?rq=1)" for the answer...

You need to set the tabindex attribute of the div as given below:

```
<div id="example" tabindex="1" />
```