# Numeric Fields on HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, numerical, onkeypress, decimal-point

I have been trying to allow numeric field and one decimal point in my Grid.Its work fine when its suitable for input box.

when i am calling  **onKeyPress** the script work fine for "input box" rather than on "Div element"

In "*Div element*",when i am supposed to use this .It allow to  access only for number rather Alphabet

hence,while coming to "*decimal place*" its not working as it should.[ It's allowing many Dot's]

```
<script>  
       function getKey(e)  
      {  
        if (window.event)  
           return window.event.keyCode;  
        else if (e)  
           return e.which;  
        else  
           return null;  
      }  
      function restrictChars(e, obj)  
      {  
        var CHAR_AFTER_DP = 2;  // number of decimal places  
        var validList = "0123456789.";  // allowed characters in field  
        var key, keyChar;  
        key = getKey(e);  
        if (key == null) return true;  
        // control keys  
        // null, backspace, tab, carriage return, escape  
        if ( key==0 || key==8 || key==9 || key==13 || key==27 )  
           return true;  
        // get character  
        keyChar = String.fromCharCode(key);  
        // check valid characters  
        if (validList.indexOf(keyChar) != -1)  
        {  
          // check for existing decimal point  
          var dp = 0;  
          if( (dp = obj.value.indexOf( ".")) > -1)  
          {  
            if( keyChar == ".")  
              return false;  // only one allowed  
            else  
            {  
              // room for more after decimal point?  
              if( obj.value.length - dp <= CHAR_AFTER_DP)  
                return true;  
            }  
          }  
          else return true;  
        }  
        // not a valid character  
        return false;  
      }  
    </script>  

<div onKeyPress="return restrictChars(event, this)">
```

Any Ideas how we could achieve it

Comment: What is use case for 'keyPress' event on 'div' and how one would press key in the div?

Comment: Are you talking about applying this to a content-editable div? Also, regarding your test for characters after the decimal point, you do realise the user can click at the start of a field that already has several digits and add a decimal point there?

Comment: I have been using handson-table Grid.so,I need to restrict each every cell to allow only numeric & decimal.For that,purpose I have been using above given Script.But it allow's me to restrict number. Decimal point i couldn't achieve it.

Comment: ah,consider for eg( if user as an "Div" element and he also as 5 input box is beneath  div)why can't we use "onkeypress" property as common on div element .Tell me if am wrong @budhram

Comment: user2742540: Check this for binding keypress event in div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capturing-key-press-event-in-div since they way you are doing it is wrong. In your case, 'obj' will always refer to 'div' not particular 'input' box. Hence, 'obj.value' always be 'undefined' since value is not defined for 'div'. It you want to use jQuery, then check 'Alex' solution.

Comment: Thank u for quick response @budhram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `<input>`, it is required to check the `value` attribute, hence why `obj.value` is used in your code above. A `div` element doesn't have a `value` attribute. You have to check it's `innerHTML` ([mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)). If you replace all instances of `obj.value` with `obj.innerHTML`, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery `keypress()` method to handle this right:

```
$("#d input").keypress(function(event){
    return restrictChars(event);
});
```

See the working fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ePvJ8/1/