# .onkeydown only take effect when focus one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make the keyboard control for my slider. But I have a problem, it take effect even when I type in input search. How can I make it only take effect when I focus on slider?

My HTML:

```
<nav class="grey lighten-3 search"> // I don't want this element to be take effect by window.onkeydown
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="searchbox">
        <form>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" type="search" required>
            <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This my slider HTML:

```
<div class="row slider-container">
  <div class="col s12 category">
    <p>Slide</p>
  </div>
  <div id="slide" class="slider-content carousel col s12">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img class="lazyload" data-src="http://img02.deviantart.net/82fc/i/2013/175/2/7/aku_no_hana__poster_i__by_fikandzo-d6airxz.png" alt="Lazy Image">
      Caption</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img class="lazyload" data-src="http://img02.deviantart.net/82fc/i/2013/175/2/7/aku_no_hana__poster_i__by_fikandzo-d6airxz.png" alt="Lazy Image">
      Caption</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img class="lazyload" data-src="http://img02.deviantart.net/82fc/i/2013/175/2/7/aku_no_hana__poster_i__by_fikandzo-d6airxz.png" alt="Lazy Image">
      Caption</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img class="lazyload" data-src="http://img02.deviantart.net/82fc/i/2013/175/2/7/aku_no_hana__poster_i__by_fikandzo-d6airxz.png" alt="Lazy Image">
      Caption</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
    document.onkeydown = function() {
            switch (window.event.keyCode) {
            case 37:
            abb.trigger('abb.prev');
            break;
            case 39:
            abb.trigger('abb.next');
            break;
            case 65:
            abb.trigger('abb.prev');
            break;
            case 68:
            abb.trigger('abb.next');
            break;
            }
    };
```

Comment: Where is your HTML code? Include **all relevant** code...

Comment: You can make use of `e` as parameter to `function()` and get which is the `target` that triggered `e` using `e.target` or `e.target.nodeName` and if it is from slider then perform actions otherwise let it do what it is supposed to do!!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean but thank you. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

You can define the onkeydown on the div only

```
var slider= document.getElementById('slide');
slider.onkeydown=function(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you may have to set your slider-container selectable thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element) trick : `<div class="row slider-container" tabindex="1">`

Then just bind the event listener on your slider, so that it will be executed only when you focus the slider:

```
document.querySelector(".slider-container").onkeydown = function(event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 37:
            abb.trigger('abb.prev');
            break;
            case 39:
            abb.trigger('abb.next');
            break;
            case 65:
            abb.trigger('abb.prev');
            break;
            case 68:
            abb.trigger('abb.next');
            break;
            }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.It work correctly but I still got same problem :D... I'll find another way..

Comment: you mean that the function is executed even when the slider is not focused ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work correctly because I forgot that slider plugin create some div inside .slider-container (such as .drag or navigation bar) and I can't focus on .slider-container.
All I want is this function isn't excuted when I type somewhere like input search.

Comment: Oh so just change the selector to #slide, it should be better :)