# .addEventListener enquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this works:

```
$('#divID').addEventListener('click', function() {alert('hi');}, false);
```

However I'm trying to get this to work, but just couldn't

```
$('#divID').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    e = event || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        //do something when the down arrow key is pressed.
    }
}, false);
```

Please help, much appreciated.

I'm trying to control what happens when the down arrow key is pressed but it's only for that specific divID, not for the whole document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element

Comment: *"So this works"* Um...it does? You sure? Pretty sure you'll find jQuery instances don't have an `addEventListener` method.

Comment: Why are you using `addEventListener` on a jQuery object? This should be throwing an error, so I'm not sure how it can possibly be working. Use `on()`, `click()` or `keypress()` instead

Comment: I'm using Pagepiling, which is one of the parallax scrolling plugin, each <div> forms a scrollable section. I just want to make sure I can enable the down key to do other things apart from just scrolling down to the next section.

Comment: For instance, the way in which the former code has been working for me is that if given a specific section of #divID, when you click anywhere in that section, it appears that there is an alert message, now I just want to replicate that, but by pressing the down key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged your question `jquery`, so I'll assume you are actually using it.

There are several issues there:

1. `keypress` is only triggered for *printable* characters. For arrow keys, you want `keydown` (usually) or `keyup` (rarely).
2. jQuery instances don't have an `addEventListener` method. You want `on`. (Or you could use the event-specific alias for the event you want to use.)
3. There is no third argument to the jQuery `on` method.
4. jQuery handles the issue of the event argument being passed by some handler mechanisms and not by others for you. It always gives you the argument.
5. Some browsers use `keyCode`, others use `which`. jQuery standardizes it for you as `which`.

So:

```
$('#divID').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40) {
        //do something when the down arrow key is pressed.
    }
});
```

More: [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on), [the event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

For the `div` to receive the keypress, on at least some browsers, it will need to either be or have interactive content (for instance, it would need to have an `input` in it, or be `contenteditable`, or similar).

**Live Example with a `contenteditable` `div`**

```js
$('#divID').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {
    //do something when the down arrow key is pressed.
    $("<p>").text("down arrow").appendTo(document.body);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="divID" contenteditable>Click here to ensure the div has focus, then press the down arrow</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, capture the keydown event on `document.body` (or `document`):

**Live Example with `document.body`:**

```js
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {
    //do something when the down arrow key is pressed.
    $("<p>").text("down arrow").appendTo(document.body);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="divID">Click here to ensure the document has focus, then press the down arrow</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems to have no effect when I put alert('hi'); //this doesn't show up.

Comment: @Henry: For the `div` to receive the event, it needs to be interactive in some way (for instance, `contenteditable`). Or you can capture the keypress on `document.body` or `document` instead. I've added live examples to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, however despite the fact that it's working on your code snippet, my code still doesn't work oddly.

Comment: @Henry: If you update your question with a [mcve], we may be able to help you. Otherwise, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Okay I'll update the post ASAP, thank you for being here to help me.

Comment: Actually T.J. Crowder it seems that when I am reposting my code, the question appears to be different as I have changed the .addeventlistener to your suggestion of using .on

Comment: I discovered that after I changed my code after your suggestion (it works to a certain extent) but the nature of the problem has changed. I'll accept this to be the correct answer. Thank you for your time and help T.J. Crowder. Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

`KeyPress` event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, `KeyDown` event is raised for all including nonprintable.

> Also the behaviour varies from browser to browser.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I'll keep in mind for the future