# How to bind to keydown event of li tag in Angular2?

Tags: angular

using `(click)="onSelect(hero)`, I can bind to click event of `li` tag.
I can also bind to `mouseover` event of `li` tag.
But I can't bind to `keydown` event of `li` tag.
`li` tag supports `click,mouseover,keydown` propety, so I think I can use `keydown` event(down arrow) to navigate to the next item in this list box.

Where is the official docs I can look for?

```
    <div class = "body-container">
        <ul class = "heroes">
            <li *ngFor = "let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" (keydown)="onKeydown()" (mouseover)="onKeydown()" class="bl-list-item" [class.bl-list-item-checked]="hero === selectedHero">
                <div class="guide-label">
                    <span style="width:50px" [class.fa-check]="hero === selectedHero" [class.li-fa-check]="hero === selectedHero"></span>
                    <div class="guide-code-column">{{hero.id}}</div>
                    <div class="guide-name-column">{{hero.name}}</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    export class SearchComponent {
        heroes: Hero[] = [];
        selectedHero: Hero;

        constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.heroService.getHeroes()
            .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
        }

        showDialog = false;

        onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
            this.selectedHero = hero;
        }

        onKeydown(): void {
            console.log("onKeydown");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Google Google Google

Comment: I didn't find any useful inforamtion. I don't know what keywords I can use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is a question asking how to do this with jquery comparable to asking how to do this in Angular2? I am curious for multiple reasons. But binding a key down event in angular 2 using typescript and event binding would not typically be done with jquery right?

Comment: It's not about jQuery but with jQuery you also need to focus the element and for that the element needs to have a `tabindex`. This is all browser stuff unrelated to the framework you're using. The event binding itself is fine int the code in the question already anyway.

Comment: Ok gotcha thanks. I did not realize that. I am using angular2 a lot lately so I was wondering if it was common to use jqeury for things like that and I was missing something lol. Thanks man.

Answer (score 5):

You basically start with the event-type and then add a series of dot-delimited modifiers. For example:

> First, the limitations. The native KeyEventsPlugin plugin only support
>   keydown and keyup events, not keypress. And, these key combinations
>   can only be bound to a specific element (or host) - the plugin doesn't
>   appear to support the global "document:" or "window:" event-scope.
>   There is also no implicit support for browser-overrides. Meaning, if
>   you need to cancel the default-behavior of the key-combination, you
>   have to do it yourself (with $event.preventDefault()).

```
keydown.a
keydown.b
keydown.c
keydown.dot
keydown.Spacebar
keydown.meta.Enter
keydown.alt.Enter
keydown.control.Enter
keydown.shift.Enter
keydown.meta.o
keydown.meta.s
keydown.meta.f
keydown.escape
```

The "special key" modifiers are:

alt
control
meta - The Command key on Mac and the Windows key on Windows.
shift
There are then two replacement keys that are there just keep the syntax from breaking:

Space - Or, you can use "Spacebar".
Dot - Since the modifiers are dot-delimited.

```
  <input
    (keydown.Enter)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Enter' )"
    (keydown.alt.Enter)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'ALT + Enter' )"                                   (keydown.control.Enter)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Control + Enter' )"
    (keydown.meta.Enter)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Meta + Enter' )"
    (keydown.shift.Enter)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Shift + Enter' )"
    (keydown.Escape)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Escape' )"
    (keydown.ArrowLeft)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Left' )"
    (keydown.ArrowUp)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Up' )"
    (keydown.ArrowRight)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Right' )"
    (keydown.ArrowDown)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Down' )"
 autofocus>
```

Answer (score 2):

The element has to be focused and for that it needs to be an input element or have the `tabindex` set to `>= "0"`.

See also [Capture key press (or keydown) event on DIV element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element)

You can capture keyboard events globally like `(window:keydown)="onKeydown($event)"` but I don't know if this helps in your case.