# In angular2 how to detect Ctrl A key press?

Tags: angular

I have a list of items and I am trying to give file traverse behavior like file explorer to the list of items meaning after selecting an item, if you hold shift key and press down arrow those items should get selected.

I have a list as mentioned below.

```
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="mylist">
    <li  tabindex="1">item1</li>
    <li  tabindex="2">item2</li>
    <li  tabindex="3">item3</li>
    <li tabindex="4">item4</li>
    <li tabindex="5">item5</li>
    <li tabindex="6">item6</li>
    <li tabindex="7">item7</li>
    <li tabindex="8">item8</li>
    <li tabindex="9">item9</li>
    <li tabindex="10">item10</li>
</ul>
```

If I am using `(keydown.ctrl.a)="handleKey($event, item.name)"`, it's not recognizing ctrl and a button click. How can I achieve this in angular2?

Comment: Refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781064/how-to-bind-to-keydown-event-of-li-tag-in-angular2

Answer (score 18):

Use `control` instead of `ctrl`:

```
(keydown.control.a)="handleKey($event, item.name)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this in `handleKey` to detects that Ctrl + a are pressed:

```
event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('Control') && event.keyCode===65
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lp2aps)

Comment: For Chrome at the time of this comment, ctrlKey is set to false even though it's held down when the A is pressed.  A real pain. Seems we may have to track the Ctrl key going up and down separately. Then again this is AngularJS 1.27 ng-input. Maybe they fixed it since.

Comment: Further research revealed that actually the problem was caused by using keyup event, and the developer was doing it fast and raising the ctrl key before raising the A key. Took an hour of testing to figure this out.  Switched to KeyDown and life is much better. I think event.ctrlKey is the correct code to use -- not sure if getModifierState is really cross-platform. In fact, i think the above answer is wrong, because if getModifierState is not present, then the logic will fail even if they are typing Ctrl-A.