# eventListener can't read keyCode

Tags: javascript, html, events

So I'm working on a game that will accept user input (up down left right arrow keys). To do so, I will add an event listener that will check when the user presses said keys. I have it set up in the following way:

```
function gameStart(){

    //Generates four random numbers on board
    for(gameStart_i = 0; gameStart_i < 4; gameStart_i++){
        generateNumber();
    }

    document.getElementById("start_button").innerHTML = "Reset Game";
    document.getElementById("start_button").setAttribute('onclick', 'reset()');
    document.getElementById("start_button").id = 'reset_button';

    var board = document.getElementById("game_background");


    console.log("1");
    board.addEventListener("keydown", inputListen(), false);
    console.log("1.1");
}

function inputListen(e){
    console.log("2");
    var code = e.keyCode;
    switch(code){
        case 37:
            alert("left");
            break;
        case 38:
            alert("up");
            break;
        case 39:
            alert("right");
            break;
        case 40:
            alert("down");
            break;
    }
}
```

This seems in line with how tutorials show it. However, some tutorials change the addEventListener line with something that would look like this:

```
  board.addEventListener("keydown", inputListen, false); //removes the () after the function
```

However that doesn't seem to work for me when I look into my console.

When I run my code my console gives me the following error:

```
  1
  2
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined
    at inputListen (script.js:86)
    at gameStart (script.js:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (2048Game.html:114)
```

I think it's because I don't pass any parameters to my function, but none of the online tutorials pass paraements in their addEventListener statement.

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Have you really saved the file and refreshed the web page after removing `()`? The log "2" should never appear before "1.1".

Comment: When I remove it, everything works normally but I get none of the alerts when I press the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is indeed to remove the `()` after `inputListen`.
Using the `()` immediately calls the function, which then gives you aforementioned `Cannot read property 'keycode' of undefined` since no input parameters were given.

You should have also received the error in the console between the two `console.log` lines, which proves the error came from the `addEventListener` line.

You want to pass the function without calling it using the line you posted:

```
board.addEventListener("keydown", inputListen, false); //removes the () after the function
```

**Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gua5tke2/):**

```
function gameStart(){
  console.log("before");
  document.getElementById("game_background").addEventListener("keydown", inputListen, false);
  console.log("after");
}
```

This should print out to the console

```
before
after
```

And then nothing else until it detects a `keydown`.

**It also matters what kind of element you bind this to.** An element such as `<input>` will have no trouble here, but normal non-focusable elements will need the `tabindex` attribute in order to be focused and respond to a `keydown`:

```
<div id="game_background" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```

You'll need to click the element once to focus onto it, then your events should be captured. More info [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149416/7016732).

Comment: This works! The issue was resolved when I changed my element to which I bound the event listener. I changed it from the game background to the button. I didn't know about focusable elements and will read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes drop the `()`, you are using the function itself to the event listener, not the result of the function call.
2. The `keydown` event is likely *not* sent to an arbitrary `<div>` in the page. Add the event listener to the window itself instead, if you don't want the user to manually click to focus on it.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', inputListen);
```