# HostListener to analyse combination key press

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to trace when a user presses a Shift+Tab combination key using keyboard, but I am not able to fire that event

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])

onkeyup(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 16 && event.keyCode == 9) {
    this.isShift = true;
    console.log("On Keyup " + event.keyCode);
  }
}

onkeydown(event) {
  console.log("On KeyDown" + event.keyCode);
}
```

Comment: your post here actually became an answer to my question... how to listen to either mouse event or keyboard event. And the solution is by stacking HostListener Annotations on a function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It works when I do this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[test-directive]'
})
export class TestDirective {
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) {
      console.log('shift and tab');
    }
  }
}

<input type="text" test-directive />
```

Note that `keyup` can be tricky because `tab` may unfocus the element. So by the time `keyup` fires, you may be on the next element, so `keyup` may actually fire on that element. So it depends on what you need. But `keydown` works for the current element.

Comment: Is it possible to use test-directive inside a Component?
Eg: I have <split-view></split-view> component, i want to track the Shift+Tab Event inside this component

Comment: Yes, it will work if you put `test-directive` on an element that contains other elements which can fire `keydown` events, because the events bubble. Note that non-input elements like plain `div` elements may not fire `keydown` events unless you add `tabindex`. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element

Comment: @FrankModica, how about if I want to capture either mouse event or keyboard event? Thanks.

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul I'm sorry I haven't worked with this in a while. Maybe you need more HostListeners.

Answer (score 31):

Although the solution by Frank Modica works, using [Angular's key event filtering and pseudo-events](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter) would be a more readable and cleaner solution:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[keyHandler]'
})
export class KeyHandlerDirective {

    @HostListener('keydown.shift.tab', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(e) {
        // optionally use preventDefault() if your combination
        // triggers other events (moving focus in case of Shift+Tab)
        // e.preventDefault();
        console.log('shift and tab');
    }
}

// in template:
<input type="text" keyHandler />
```

More examples of how pseudo-events work can be found [here](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/angular-pseudo-events-d4e7f89247ee).

Comment: Angular's documentation is awful on this but this article helped me: https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/angular-pseudo-events-d4e7f89247ee

Comment: @MithunSudheendran Maybe you want to mark this solution as the accepted answer? It is cleaner than mine :)