# How to add keyboard event on `div` without contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to listen on `ctrl + c` key event on a `div` dom. I know I can add `keypress` event on the dom by setting its `contentEditable` to true (see below code). But it will make the div editable. What I want is to listen on `ctrl + c` event not make the div editable. Is there a way for me to do that?

```
$('.mydiv').attr('contentEditable', true);
$('.mydiv').focus();
$('.mydiv').bind('keypress', handler);
```

Comment: Will the `<div>` have `:focus` when you're pressing `ctrl + c` ?

Comment: An element, what is not editable, can't have this events. You could listen to the whole document only, and see what is selected if `ctrl+c` is pressed.

Comment: [Link Might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

Comment: read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. 
Run this in your debugger on this current page:

```
document.querySelector('.post-taglist').oncopy = _ => alert('CCCCCCC')
```

[image]

it should make entire div (marked on screenshot with yellow color) listen to copy event (CTRL + C). Now you can click anywhere on the div (for example, where red circle is marked on the screenshot), than CTRL + C and you should get alert 'CCCCCCC'

Comment: The `contentEditable` will make the div editable which I don't want.

Comment: do not add `contentEditable`

Answer (score 0):

If you add `tabindex="0"` to your `<div>` it will be able to get `:focus` without using `contentEditable`. You can then list for the `ctrl + c` like so:

```
var ctrlDown = false,
    ctrlKey = 17,
    cKey = 67;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if($('div').is(":focus")){
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
    if (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == cKey){
        alert('dave');
        ctrlDown = false;
    }
  }
})
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m12nyeg4/) to see it working.