# DIV with tabindex: capture key event but skip on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I need a `<div>` that should be able to get key down events. For that reason I have to add the attribute `tabindex="0"`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element).

The "collateral effect" is that the `<div>` become "tabbable" and this is not desired because tab should just traverse input fields.

Is there a "trick" to avoid it or the only way is to catch the tab event, search for the next input field (so skipping DIVs) and than prevent the default behavior?

Comment: Why you want div to have key down events and don't want to have focus on that element. You want to get keydown events when click it?

Comment: Yes I want keydown events but I don't want the element to be traversable with tab

Comment: what about setting tabindex="-1"? Seems to work in FF an Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can test with this.

```js
function doSomething(ctrl)
{
    // Prevent default behaviour
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (event.key === 'Enter')
    {
        ctrl.innerHTML = 'Enter is pressed';
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowDown')
    {
        ctrl.innerHTML = 'ArrowDown is pressed';
    }
}
```

```html
<div onkeydown="doSomething(this);" contenteditable="true" readonly style="outline:none;">flsdkjflsajdflkasjdlfkjsaldfkjlksadfj</div>
```

Comment: I have tested it, but it only works if contenteditable="true", which is not my case!

Comment: Ok, the **readonly** attribute prevents edits and you can style the div with no outline. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting tabindex="-1"? Seems to work in FF an Chrome